# Making a footer for a div element

Tags: html, css

so i want to make this footer style :
[image: Github's Footer]
I tried my best, and i got this :
[image: My Footer]
How can i make it combine like the first picture?

I've tried my best and this is my code so far :

```css
div.code-div{
    border:solid 1px #bababa;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:Code;
    font-size:5em;
    border-bottom: solid 50px #b0b0b0;
}

div.code-div ::selection{
    background-color:#adddff;
}

div.footer{
    background:#b0b0b0;
    border-top: solid 1px #b0b0b0;
    border:solid 1px #b0b0b0;
}

b.footertext{
    font-size:20%;
}

a.viewraw{
    float:right;
    font-size:20%;
}

table.code{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display:block;
    width:100%
}

td.linenum{
    font-family:Code;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#bababa;
    user-select: none;
}

td.linecode{
    font-family:Code;
    font-size:10px;
}

span.builtins.import{
    color:#ffa938;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="0embed.css">
<div class="code-div">
    <div>
        <table class="code">
            <tr>
                <td class="linenum">1</td>
                <td class="linecode"><span class="none"><span class="builtins import">import</span> PySimpleGUI <span class="builtins import">as</span> sg</span></td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <b class="footertext">Exampletext</b>
        <a class="viewraw">view raw</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the text, as in the 2nd picture doesn't combine with the border, how am i supposed to combine them?
I Really Appreciate If You Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have padding on your `.code-div` and the `.footer` is inside that so won't go all the way to the edges. To make it work how you want, you should remove the padding from `.code-div` and add it to the `.footer`.

```
div.code-div{
    border:solid 1px #bababa;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-family:Code;
    font-size:5em;
    border-bottom: solid 50px #b0b0b0;
}

div.footer{
    background:#b0b0b0;
    border-top: solid 1px #b0b0b0;
    border:solid 1px #b0b0b0;
    padding:5px;
}
```